# Making a wide table, collapse into rows on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

We have some product data that has varying table data. Sometimes there is 2 column, then perhaps 4. When there is 4 columns, it causes problems on mobile and doesn't fit with our responsive layout.

Can anyone help get the table to work better on mobile.

Here is the original table: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnjsv48g/

A guide I am using: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Here is my responsive attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/f1z6czeo/

```html
<table align="center" border="2" style="height:445px; width:761px">
        <caption>Technical Information</caption>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Washer Speeds</td>
                <td>Speed 1</td>
                <td>Speed 2</td>
                <td>Speed 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Revs per minute squared</td>
                <td>480m³/hr</td>
                <td>600m³/hr</td>
                <td>950³/hr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Extraction Rate ³/hr Recirculated</td>
                <td>322m³/hr</td>
                <td>402m³/hr</td>
                <td>636m³/hr</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Noise Levels DB/A</td>
                <td>54 DB</td>
                <td>57 DB</td>
                <td>63 DB</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Minimum Height of Product</td>
                <td>No Less Than 650mm From Your Base</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DPP Rating</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Backup Filter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Optional Extra)</td>
                <td>Round 5 (2 Filters required)</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Light Options</td>
                <td>2x 1.2w LED Bulk BBT299</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Marble Size &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; (Marble Kit optional Extra)</td>
                <td>125mm Minimum(150mm is recommended)(Up to 4 Mtr&nbsp;&nbsp; Only)</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Remote Control</td>
                <td>No</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Warranty &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; (Subject to registration)</td>
                <td>3 years</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BPP Scheme Colour Code</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BOR Rand Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Cleaner Safe)</td>
                <td>Y</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Box Type</td>
                <td>3 Amp</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gang Type</td>
                <td>Toggle Control</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <table border="0" style="height:82px; width:273px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="/Installation Instruction.pdf" target="_blank" title="60cm curved glass cooker hoods tech sheet"><img alt="pdf icon" src="https://s18.postimg.org/wlzpg6c21/PDF_Logo_2.png" style="float:left; height:75px; margin-right:20px; width:75px"></a></td>
                            <td>Installation Guide<br>
                            PDF File - Opens in a New Window</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                <table border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="/install_guide.pdf" target="_blank" title="60cm curved glass cooker hoods tech sheet"><img alt="pdf icon" src="https://s18.postimg.org/wlzpg6c21/PDF_Logo_2.png" style="float:left; height:75px; margin-right:20px; width:75px"></a></td>
                            <td>Product Specification Guide<br>
                            PDF File - Opens in a New Window</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: look at my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/f4bhnn3g/

Comment: Looking good, just a bit of a wobble at the footer with PDF links. Which I suppose don't fit into 3 option format, hence the alignment issues

Comment: Is there a way for the "Marble Size (Marble Kit optional Extra)" not to span on multiple rows more than it needs to.

Comment: if you delete &nbsp; in marble kit it won't span

Comment: aligned pdf's cells and space set to nowrap: https://jsfiddle.net/4pjf5v63/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an solution: look at snippet

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px){

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}

table, thead, tbody, th {
    display: block;
}
tbody, td, tr {
    display: inline-block;
}

thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
tr.techinfo {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.techinfo > td {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.techinfo > td:first-child {
  width: 39%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 4em;
}
.techinfo > td:nth-child(2){
    background: #bbb;
}
.techinfo > td:nth-child(3){
    background: #ccc;
}
.techinfo > td:nth-child(4){
    background: #ddd;
}
.docs {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.docs > td {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.docs > td > table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
.docs > td tr {
  border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="2">
 <caption>Technical Information</caption>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Washer Speeds</td>
   <td>Speed 1</td>
   <td>Speed 2</td>
   <td>Speed 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Revs per minute squared</td>
   <td>480m³/hr</td>
   <td>600m³/hr</td>
   <td>950³/hr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Extraction Rate ³/hr Recirculated</td>
   <td>322m³/hr</td>
   <td>402m³/hr</td>
   <td>636m³/hr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Noise Levels DB/A</td>
   <td>54 DB</td>
   <td>57 DB</td>
   <td>63 DB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Minimum Height of Product</td>
   <td>No Less Than 650mm From Your Base</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>DPP Rating</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Backup Filter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Optional Extra)</td>
   <td>Round 5 (2 Filters required)</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Light Options</td>
   <td>2x 1.2w LED Bulk BBT299</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Marble Size (Marble Kit optional Extra)</td>
   <td>125mm Minimum(150mm is recommended)(Up to 4 Mtr Only)</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Remote Control</td>
   <td>No</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Warranty(Subject to registration)</td>
   <td>3 years</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>BPP Scheme Colour Code</td>
   <td>N/A</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>BOR Rand Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Cleaner Safe)</td>
   <td>Y</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Box Type</td>
   <td>3 Amp</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="techinfo">
   <td>Gang Type</td>
   <td>Toggle Control</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="docs">
   <td> 
   <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td><a href="/Installation Instruction.pdf" target="_blank" title="60cm curved glass cooker hoods tech sheet"><img alt="pdf icon" src="https://s18.postimg.org/wlzpg6c21/PDF_Logo_2.png" style="float:left; height:75px; margin-right:20px; width:75px"></a></td>
      <td>Installation Guide<br>
      PDF File - Opens in a New Window</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
      </td>
      <td>
   <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td><a href="/install_guide.pdf" target="_blank" title="60cm curved glass cooker hoods tech sheet"><img alt="pdf icon" src="https://s18.postimg.org/wlzpg6c21/PDF_Logo_2.png" style="float:left; height:75px; margin-right:20px; width:75px"></a></td>
      <td>Product Specification Guide<br>
      PDF File - Opens in a New Window</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using `text-align:center` instead of `padding:50%` as this doesn't align very well.

That said, it does appear that your table re-renders at the appropriate size. What is it you are wanting it to do specifically? Could you mock-up an 'after' image?

Lastly, this may not be helpful for you if this is just a learning exercise, but a jQuery plugin exists to do exactly this: [tablesaw](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw)

Comment: This is what I was hoping for on mobiles goo.gl/G7DVS9  At the momentm in that 2nd fiddle the Speeds dont line up properly with the content